# Corine Land Cover - ESRI FGDB to .shp

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I am trying to convert the Corine Land Cover Map (version CLC18) from .gdb format to .shp. I am working on QGIS. I tried `Export>Save Feature as>ESRI Shapefile` but it didnt work. The log file with the errors lives here: https://pastebin.com/8QiKw6nj 
 Any ideas?

UPDATE:

Also tried using OSGeo4W with `C:\>ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" F:/n F:\DownloadsFromExplorer\clc2018_clc2018_v2018_20_fgdb/CLC2018_CLC2018_V2018_20.gdb` . The error log file: https://pastebin.com/1Vypvr1f

Comment: Please share your errors and describe the way how does your initial shapefile look like with us.

Comment: The log file with the errors lives here: https://pastebin.com/8QiKw6nj

Comment: The initial file is in .gdb format.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: I am familiar with the rules. I think i provided a specific question. And in the comment section, right above, after being asked, i added the error log file.

Comment: Seems like shape_length and shape_area fields are causing problems. Uncheck them in the export dialogue. They are not needed (or can be recreated later.)

Comment: use the [edit] link to add the relevant part of the log file directly to the question - don't know which site you are from but that's how we do it around here

Comment: @IanTurton Not everyone can determine what the relevant part of a logfile is. If they could you wouldn't really need pages like Stackoverflow

Comment: It seems that you have quite a large dataset and the size of the resulting shapefile exceeds the 4 GB limit `ERROR 1: Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294960868 + 11320.`. 4 GB is special for GDAL, the normal max limit is 2 GB. Use GeoPackage as outputformat instead.

Answer (score 1):

The CORINE Dataset is a pretty big dataset with some long fields in the attribute table. The old and clunky shapefile can't handle both of these very well (at all).

See for example: [SwitchFromShapefile](http://switchfromshapefile.org/)

So if you do not really need it as a Shapefile for a specific workflow, which can't handle .gdb or even better .gkpg, then you can try what @BERA suggested. Otherwise I would strongly suggest to stay in .gdb or .gpkg because this type of file is really quite unsuitable for the shapefile format.